# Boxcar convolve a scatter plot in python/astropy?

Tags: python, smoothing, scatter, astropy

I believe the fix to this will be relatively simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to convolve a scatter plot that I've plotted in python.

I have 2 data arrays, one of galactic latitudes and one of galactic longitudes, and I've plotted them with a hammer projection to represent a distribution of stars in galactic coordinates.

Now, I want to use boxcar smoothing to smooth the plot with 15 degree boxes.
I have tried using astropy.convolution with convolve and Box2DKernel, but I can't seem to make it work. 
I've also looked at examples from http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/convolution/kernels.html
but I don't understand how to translate their examples to what I need to do. They seem to be plotting a 2D function and smoothing that. Can I not convolve a plot and bin up the points by where they are on the graph? The only thing that I've gotten to display anything produces a straight line and I don't understand why. I'm very new to python so this has been giving me a lot of trouble.

This is the code that I have so far:

This plots the two arrays into a hammer projection:

```
from astropy import units as u
import astropy.coordinates as coord
glat = coord.Angle(pos_data['GLAT']*u.degree)
glon = coord.Angle(pos_data['GLON']*u.degree)
glon= glon.wrap_at(180*u.degree)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(211, projection="hammer")
ax.scatter(glon.radian, glat.radian)
ax.grid(True)
```

This is my attempt at convolving the data:

```
from astropy.convolution import convolve, Box2DKernel
data = [glon, glat]
kernel = Box2DKernel(10)
smoothed = convolve(data, kernel)

ax = fig.add_subplot(212, projection="hammer")
ax.scatter(smoothed[0]*u.radian, smoothed[1]*u.radian)
ax.grid(True)
```

Like I said, it's just one of many attempts that ended up giving something instead of an error, but I'm not sure that I'm using the function correctly at all. I'm not sure (or I don't think) that I can create "data" the way that I did, but any other combination of arrays or convolving each as a 1D array didn't work either.

Any ideas would be really helpful, thanks.

Comment: Hi Abb, Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you post the code and ask specific place where you might need help rather than pointing to tutorial?

Comment: I added the current code that I have above. Thanks!

Comment: Convolution can only be applied to regularly gridded data, whereas what you have is a collection of points.  I think you are looking for histograms, not convolution.  Try binning the data using matplotlib.pyplot.hist or numpy.histogram and plotting that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for [Kernel Density Estimation](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/), which is a way of turning individual measurements of spatial point patterns into a continuous distribution. I happen to prefer the [scikit-learn implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_digits_kde_sampling.html). You can then use the `basemap` package to do your plotting. The following code should be adaptable to your situation, where `ra` and `dec` are arrays of your stars' Right Ascension and Declination (you'll have to be careful about radians vs degrees here):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

data = np.column_stack((ra, dec))

# use a tophat/boxcar kernel and a haversine (spherical) metric
p = {'bandwidth': np.logspace(-1, 1, 20), 'kernel'='tophat', 
     'metric'='haversine'}
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(), params)
grid.fit(data)
```

Then you should be able to define a `meshgrid` over which to evaluate your KDE, and then plot it using `imshow`/`pcolormesh`/something else over a Hammer projection (see [here](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/hammer.html) or [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/geo_demo.html))